# Clicking over a menu item adds directory to current URL in Django

Tags: django, url, nav

I have an issue with my navigation menu items. When the user is in the page of **Item X** and they click over to the **Item Y** of the navigation menu, they should be taken to  `example.com/ItemY`. Instead, they are taken to `example.com/ItemX/ItemY` which results in a page-not-found error:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/biology/ItemX/ItemY
Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
[name='home']
chemistry/<slug:slug>/ [name='chemi']
summernote/
blog/ <str:parent>/<slug:slug>/ [name='blog_list']
^media/(?P<path>.*)$
The current path, blog/biology/ItemX/ItemY, didn’t match any of these.
```

These are my project url patterns:

```
#urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('chemistry.urls')),
    path('summernote/', include('django_summernote.urls')),
    path('blog/', include('blog.urls')),
]
```

And these are my app urls:

```
#blog/urls.py
urlpatterns = [
path('<str:parent>/<slug:slug>/', views.BlogDetail.as_view(), name='blog_list'),
]
```

And here is the HTML template that contains the navbar:

```
<div class="card-body">
    <nav><ul>
    {% for blog in blog_list %}
     <li><a href="{{blog.slug}}">{{blog.title}}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul></nav>
</div>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You are using relative urls not starting with a _leading slash_ so they are considered relative from the _current page_ which in your case is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/biology/ItemX/`. You should be using the `url` template tag instead of manually writing the url.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I understand. I just changed `<a href="{{blog.slug}}">` to `<a href="{% url 'blog_list' %}">` but now I get a `Reverse for 'blog_list' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['blog/(?P<parent>[^/]+)/(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$']`

Answer (score 0):

To solve this I changed the `<a>` tags to this:

```
<li><a class='text-muted' href="{{ blog.get_absolute_url }}">{{blog.title}}</a></li>
```

And I added a get_absolute_url method to the Blog model:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse("blog_list", args=[str(self.parent), str(self.slug)])
```